# SQL Server - Assign string from a list in equal manner

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a list of 20 rows. Each row represents a list of tasks to be assigned.

CREATE TABLE T (TASK_ID as STRING, ASSIGNER_ID as STRING). INSERT INTO T ('ABCD', NULL) INSERT INTO T ('BCDE', NULL) INSERT INTO T ('CDEF', NULL) etc....

My purpose is assign in a random way each task from a list (i.e. Jon-Joe-Dave-Mike), but the total load for each person has to be equal.

In this case (20 tasks - 4 persons) the maximum value is 5.
How I can assign the tasks to those in SQL Server?

Many thanks!

Comment: Please _don't_ store your data like `Jon-Joe-Dave-Mike`, which is unnormalized and difficult to work with.  Get each name into a separate record.

Comment: With properly normalized data, `NTILE` can be used to distribute rows evenly into groups.

Comment: Can you share your table structure(s), some sample data, and the result you'd like to get for this sample?

Comment: Edit in additional information in your question itself -- comments are fleeting, and terrible for formatting. You can use [this handy generator](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) to get friendly markup. `CREATE TABLE`/`INSERT` statements are always preferred because they allow the folks at home to play along.

Comment: CREATE TABLE T (TASK_ID as STRING, ASSIGNER_ID as STRING).
INSERT INTO T ('ABCD', NULL)
INSERT INTO T ('BCDE', NULL)
INSERT INTO T ('CDEF', NULL)
etc....in total I have 20 records

I want to assign to each task an assigner, with the same workload for each assigner. So, with 20 records, each assigner in a list of 4 persons should have 5 tasks assigned

Comment: Below your question, you should see the "edit" link (it may be called "improve this question" instead, this text varies by reputation and possibly whether you're the asker). Essential information on the question shouldn't linger in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax will assign 5 random tasks to each person:

```
DECLARE @p table(id int identity, name varchar(40))
DECLARE @t table(id int, taskname varchar(50))

INSERT @p values('Joe'),('Mark'),('Demi'),('Thomas')

INSERT @t(id)
VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11)
      ,(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20)

UPDATE @t set taskname = 'task' + cast(id as varchar(2))

;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT taskname, ntile(4) over(order by newid()) rnd_id
  FROM @t
)
SELECT p.name, cte.taskname
FROM CTE
JOIN @p p
ON p.id = cte.rnd_id
```

Comment: Perfect! It works! Great!
Just a quick question: if in example I have 30 tasks and 4 assigners, how can I modify the query in order to have the same workloads except for 2 assigners? In this case should be (7 7 8 8). Thank you!! =D

Comment: change ntile(4) to ntile(5), add an extra person to table **@p** and add the 10 tasks to the table **@t**.  Be aware the last 2 people will always get fewer tasks